# Impossible to find core_config_data table

Tags: magento2, database, domain

A very noob question: it's my first time working on Magento2 e-commerce and I would like to move pages from IP to the domain name.

Reading the documentation, I've found that I've to edit the core_config_data table in PHPMyAdmin. The problem is that actually there isn't such a table in my DB...

Is this normal? I'm not a developer and the guy that made the installation doesn't respond to my emails.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's not normal :).. It must there core_config_data

Comment: I'm sure that there is a core_config_data table in there otherwise your website would not work. Try to run this query `select * from core_config_data limit 10` just to see if you get some results.

Comment: without core_config_data table magento setup will not work, maybe you are searching in some other database. check database name at app/etc/env.php file

Comment: if it is magento, then there should be a core_config_data table. may be tables are created with some prefix. try to run query and check if you get any result. `select * from core_config_data limit 1`

Comment: Thanks @Marius. It works!